# Run query across multiple databases to find out how many times a username is duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a single tenancy web app (every single tenant has their own database).  I am trying to move it to a multi tenancy architecture, but before I do this I am trying to identify conflicts.

Currently I am trying to figure out which usernames might be duplicated between the many different tenants.

My solution so far is to write a query that does something like this:

```
SELECT `user`, count(*) FROM (     
    (SELECT * FROM `100001`.`user`) UNION
    (SELECT * FROM `100002`. `user`) UNION
    (SELECT * FROM `100003`. `user`) UNION
    (SELECT * FROM `100004`. `user`) UNION
    (SELECT * FROM `100005`. `user`) UNION
    ...
) as `all_users`
GROUP BY `user`
```

This works great, but does not scale well when you realize there are already over 100 databases.

I start thinking about using CONCAT to help me generate the query but got stuck at this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('(SELECT * FROM `', SCHEMA_NAME, '`.`user`)')
FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` WHERE `SCHEMA_NAME` REGEXP '[0-9]{6}';
```

Any thoughts on where to go from here?

Comment: Cursor and or dynamic sql would be the usual way. Though, I'm not seeing why you need it in this example. You aren't going to key the user table by user name, are you?

Comment: You might want to generate the statements using a scripting language external to MySQL where this sort of thing is trivial.

Comment: @tadman, getting a script to run against the database would require a decent amount of work. I currently only have permission to run queries against the production database.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do this with one hand tied behind your back.